# Asynchronously loading an image to use as a property

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Say we have a `User` class with properties `id: Int`, `name: String`, `imageUrl: String`.

Our imaginary API stores the URL to the image. Is there a way to fetch this image once, and then reuse it in many places across the app as if it were another variable like `name`? I'm basically trying to be able to call `user.image` as a property after I fetch it.

I have no issues asynchronously fetching the image, but I can't figure out how I can only fetch it once, store it somewhere, and reuse it as a class variable (or at least something like it, just as simply), instead of fetching it every time I want to use it.

I'm sure many people deal with a similar type of situation where APIs return URLs to images. Is there an efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably implement this yourself but I'd recommend [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) instead. Kingfisher does exactly what you're asking for, it caches images so you only need to get them from the server once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll def take a look. What about for information that isn't necessarily images? Using a different example: Say there are `Song`s in an `Album`. If at least 1 song is explicit, the whole album is marked explicit. But the explicit info is at the song level not the album level. So when an `Album` is created, I'd like to have an explicit variable that will traverse the songs and check if at least 1 is explicit, but have it as an `Album` variable like `album.explicit` (IDK if this makes sense bt it was the best I could think of lol)

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle that. You could create a [singleton](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/88/how-to-implement-singletons-in-swift-the-smart-way) holding an array of Albums, however there are reasons that this is not ideal. 
Otherwise, you can pass the Album to other view controllers as needed using [segues](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers). For the example you mentioned, I believe the most efficient solution would be to use segues and add explicit as a property of your Album object.

Comment: You're really just looking at caching the assets locally.  Various ways to do it, but a simple solution could be done by writing the assets to disk and then adding to the async loading code a check of the cache.  You could extend UIImage to take care of this in the scenario above.  Maybe you'd want to hold a list of cached items somewhere with an expiry time.  You could have a background thread that refreshes the cached items based on expiry times.  It'll come down to what your requirements are...  You might also want to check out NSCache, as that may work for many scenarios.

Comment: @ConfuseIous Thank you, but that's what my question is. *How* can I go about adding explicit as a property of the `Album`? And then be able to use this property in several places across the app? What do I set it to? There would be an async function call since I would need to make another call to the API to get the explicit values for each `Song`.

Comment: ```struct Album {
         var isExplicit: Bool  
}
```
You can add the isExplicit property to your Album as above. I assume your Song already has a reference to the Album it belongs to so you could find said Album and verify whether it's explicit with `album.isExplicit`

Comment: @ConfuseIous Hey again. I'm a little confused by your response. I understand what you're saying by add the property to `Album`, but the "issue" is that what is that property (`isExplicit` in your example) set *to*? The logic behind it is that there would have to be an async function call to fetch all of the songs for that album, and check if at least 1 is explicit (`Song` objects aren't stored in `Album` objects, it's a separate "fetch songs for album with this ID" API call). So I'm not sure how to proceed because of the async stuff. Do you have sample code that may help me understand better?

Comment: You can handle it as usual, just do it in the completion handler. This is how I'd do it.
```var isAlbumExplicit = false

for song in songs {
    if song.isExplicit {
        isAlbumExplicit = true
        break
    }
}
```

I apologise for the broken formatting, I haven't quite got the hang of answering here yet.

Comment: @ConfuseIous Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there an issue where if I try referencing `isAlbumExplicit` somewhere in app *before* the async operation finishes, it will simply return false? So if the correct value is true but I try using the property before it's set, it would be false.

Comment: The easy way around the above issue would be to use a 3-state enum (eg. explicit, safe, unknown) rather than a bool, possibly with the song as an associated value for the first too.   But it feels like the example is leading the original question astray?